# Should I delete my answer if it later turns out to only solve one aspect of the problem

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, meta

If someone has a question with a piece of code and I "answer" by pointing out one problem with the code.

Later it turns out that there is a second problem with the code -- which i cannot solve. Hence, editing my answer is not an option.

- Should I delete my answer which is only a partial solution?
- Are there different guidelines depending on how many other answers are provided? (in my case, i was the only one answering)

**Edit:**
The reason why I am considering the deletion -- if it is the only answer -- is the following: I think people are more inclined to look at the problem if no answers are given

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the question, not in your answer. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your answer adds anything helpful to the post, you should keep it.  If the only reason you are considering deletion is because you think people are more inclined to look at the problem if no answers are given, that's not a good reason to delete a possibly helpful answer.  Questions are meant to be answered (well, most of them anyway).  Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

I think the "general" consensus is: you rather prefer to keep your answers around. See [Should I delete my own downvoted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263046/should-i-delete-my-own-downvoted-answer) for example.

The point is: anything that is "worth" asking about in the real world comes with context and nuances. Therefore questions that can be answered "100 percent" correctly are very rare (or probably very boring). Thus: as long as your answer isn't factually wrong, it might be helpful to future readers. So: keep it there. And even when your answer becomes outdated at some point, you can still *edit* it, and explain that it was true at some point, but this or that changed in the meantime ...

My personal two cent: I have plenty of 0-scored answers on stackoverflow on questions that have other great answers, and yet: from time to time, people come by, upvote one of my answers, dropping a comment that especially my content gave them some unique, helpful piece of information.